# About a right $K$-invariant function on the motion group

Tags: fourier-analysis, representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

The motion group of $\mathbb R^2$, noted by $G = M(2)$ is the semi-direct product of $\mathbb R^2$ with the special orthogonal group $K = SO(2)$. A typical element $g\in G$ is written as $g = (z, e^{i\alpha}), z \in \mathbb C, \alpha\in\mathbb R$. The group law in G is given by $$(z, e^{i\alpha})(w, e^{i\beta})=(z+e^{i\alpha} w, e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}).$$
I would like to know why a right $K$-invariant function on $G$ can be thought of as a function on $\mathbb C$ and viceversa ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** This is mostly a matter of unwinding definitions. By definition $f : G \to X$ is a right $K$-invariant function iff
$$f(g \cdot k) = f(g)$$ for all $g \in G$, $k \in K$.

Now, the right action of a typical element $k = (0, e^{i \beta}) \in K$ on a typical element $g = (z, e^{i \alpha})$ is
$$g \cdot k (z, e^{i \alpha}) \cdot (0, e^{i \beta}) = (z, e^{i (\alpha + \beta)}) .$$

> **Additional Hint** So, $f$ is right $K$-invariant iff $$f(z, e^{i (\alpha + \beta)}) = f(z, e^{i \alpha})$$ for all $z, \alpha, \beta$.

Comment: @ Travis, Yes I know that, $f$ be right K-invariant, if: $f((z,e^{i\alpha})(0,e^{i\beta})) = f(z,e^{i\alpha})$. But, Why a right $K$-invariant function on $G$, $f(z,e^{i\alpha})$,  can be thought of as a function on $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: As the additional hint says, $K$-invariance says that $f(z, e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}) = f(z, e^{i(\alpha)})$ for all $z, \alpha, \beta$. But by choosing $\alpha, \beta$ appropriately we can make $e^{i(\alpha)}$ and $e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}$ be any pair of elements $k$ and $k'$ in $\operatorname{SO}(2)$ we like. So, $f(z, k) = f(z, k')$ for all choices of $k, k'$. What does this tell you about how $f(z, k)$ depends on $k$?

Comment: Ok, from what you have written, a right $K$-invariant function $f$ depends only on the $z$-variable. So, it can be thought of as a function on $\mathbb C$. That's it?

Comment: Correct: Since $f(z, k) = f(z, k')$ for all $z, k, k'$, $f$ cannot depend on its second argument. Put more formally, $f(z, k) = g(z)$ for some function of $z$ alone.

Comment: @ Travis,  do we have the same thing in the case of the motion group of $\mathbb R^{n}$; $M(n)=\mathbb R^n \rtimes SO(n)$ ? i.e.,   $f$ be right $SO(n)$-invariant, if: $f((z,A)(0,B)) = f(z,A)$, and can be thought of as a function on $\mathbb R^{n}$ ?